# dynamic route using navigate in react not helping

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router

I want to redirect the user on Card on click event to the dynamic route. I am at `students` route now there's list  of cards. Now If I click It should redender the `User` component which is set on `Router` But I am unable to navigate. Can anyone help me here.

New to the React.

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

function CardComponent({ history }) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const data = [
    { id: '2', title: 'All', sample: '200' },
    { id: '3', title: '5th Standard', sample: '100' },
    { id: '4', title: '6th Standard', sample: '100' }
  ];
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Grid container spacing={2} direction="row" justify="flex-start" alignItems="flex-start">
        {data.map((elem) => (
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={3} key={data.indexOf(elem)}>
              ///
             /// If you see here Card click trying to naviate to the students child route
            ///
                    <Card onClick={() => navigate(`students/${elem.id}`, { replace: true })}>
                      <CardHeader
                        title={`${elem.title}`}
                        subheader={`Number of students : ${elem.sample}`}
                      />
                      <CardContent>
                        <IconWrapperStyle>
                          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faChalkboardTeacher} />
                          {/* <Icon icon={faCoffee} width={24} height={24} /> */}
                        </IconWrapperStyle>
                      </CardContent>
                    </Card>
                  </Grid>
                ))}
              </Grid>
            </div>
          );
        }
```

And this is my router below

```
{
      path: '/dashboard',
      element: currentUser ? <DashboardLayout /> : <Navigate to="/login" />,
      children: [
        { path: '/', element: <Navigate to="/dashboard/app" replace /> },
        {
          path: 'app',
          element: (
            <AuthProvider>
              <DashboardApp />
            </AuthProvider>
          )
        },
        {
          path: 'students',
          element: <StudentsCards />,
          children: [
/// here I am trying to natigate to the user Id route
            { path: ':id', element: <User /> }
          ]
        },
        { path: 'products', element: <Products /> },
        { path: 'blog', element: <Blog /> }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: What lib are you using ? Reach Router ? React Router v6 preview ? I believe the url is relative, so if you are on /students, the path you currently have will redirect to /students/students/123

Comment: `import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';` using this

Comment: Why aren't you using { Link } from 'react-router-dom' for navigation? If it's simple routing then just wrap your <Card> in 
<Link to=`your-route`><Card/></Link>.